# Error related to the Visual Studio Code from Harvard's CS50 course

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

[The blacked out region is my username.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChVua.png)

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error

I was not expecting an error there. I was just expecting the prompt I gave. This is the indoor voice project. For returning a string which has capital letter characters into small letter characters. I tested the code out in Pycharm. It wasn't showing any error.

Also When I checked their guide to do it. The username didn't appear before '$' sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might have to save the file. 'No such file' means that the file does not exist.
The white dot next to the file name implies it's not been saved.

You can turn on auto-save via the preferences dropdown.